# How to get cell value not formula in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl for to read the excel. The mention below reads the only formula but I want it to read the value of cells.

wb = load_workbook(filename='sample.xlsx',read_only=True)
ws = wb['sheet1']

Answer (score 0):

Use the data_only flag:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx',read_only=True, data_only = True)
```